# SQL Join to count based on query results

Tags: sql, join

I'm getting hung up trying to count records from one table based upon the results of a query.  My table looks like this:

```
parent_id |  site_id  | description
-----------------------------------
A1           1          FL
A1           2          NJ
A1           A1         Company_A
```

First I created a query to give me the company name on the same row as the state (description).  My initial query is:

```
SELECT master.description, sites.description, sites.site_id 
FROM sites sites
INNER JOIN sites master 
  ON sites.parent_id = master.site_id
```

Which results in:

```
Company_A     FL    1
Company_A     DE    2
```

So far so good.  What I want to do, though, is count the number of orders from the **ORDERS** table for each **site_id**, even where the number of orders are 0.

I'm stumped on how to count from the **ORDERS** table based on the results of my query?  Any help on this join would be appreciated.

UPDATE:   Almost there!  Here's what is working:

```
SELECT master.description, sites.description, count(order_id) orderCount
FROM sites sites
INNER JOIN sites master
ON sites.parent_id = master.site_id
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON sites.site_id = o.site_id
WHERE sites.site_type = 3
GROUP BY master.description, sites.description, sites.site_id
ORDER BY master.description
```

The only issue I have left is if I add a date range I get the correct results, but any sites with ZERO orders for that period are not shown.  So if I add:

```
WHERE sites.site_type = 3 AND o.order_date > '2015-10'
```

I get the correct result but only for sites with orders during that period.  What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please add the description (or preferably, the DDL) of the `orders` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this pretty easily with a LEFT Join and then a count on order id. It's important to not count the row `count(*)` because that would return a value of 1 even when there's no orders

Additionally any filtering on the orders table needs to be done inside the JOIN.

```
SELECT master.description, sites.description, sites.site_id 
       ,count(order_id) order_count 
FROM sites sites
INNER JOIN sites master 
  ON sites.parent_id = master.site_id
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON master.site_id = o.Site_id
   and   o.order_date > '2015-10'
WHERE
       sites.site_type = 3 
GROUP by
 master.description, sites.description, sites.site_id
```

You didn't describe your Order table so I'm guessing at the join criteria

Comment: THANK YOU @ConradFrix -- I used your solution and am nearly there.  I added a date range, though (see update in original post) and I'm not getting results with zero orders during the period.  Any ideas?

Comment: @StephenDundas Any filtering on the right side of a left join turns the join into an inner join. Just move `o.order_date > '2015-10` to the join clause e.g. on `ON master.site_id = o.Site_id  and o.order_date > '2015-10'` and it will fix it

Answer (score 1):

This should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT master.description, sites.description, sites.site_id,
ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders o where master.siteId = o.siteId),0) as ordersCount
FROM sites sites
INNER JOIN sites master 
  ON sites.parent_id = master.site_id
```